# Как написать скрипт, который будет автоматически удалять сообщения со стикерами во ВКонтакте?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Такая проблема, есть одни знакомый, который мне часто шлёт **стикеры**, меня это бесит и вручную удалять их это как-то очень долго, потому вот не знаю, на каком языке и как его написать.

Comment: На любом, который поддерживает HTTP и который вы знаете.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Python, он довольно простенький

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу предложить пример на [*python 3*](http://python.org)
Также для этого примера требуется установить библиотеку **vk_api**.

На Windows:

```
python.exe -m pip install vk_api
```

На Linux:

```
pip3 install vk_api
```

Вот скрипт:

```
from getpass import getpass
import sys

import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType


login = input('Логин: ')

password = getpass('Пароль: ')

vk = vk_api.VkApi(login=login, password=password)

try:
    vk.auth()
    print('Логинюсь...')
except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
    print(error_msg)
    sys.exit(1)


username = input('Короткое имя пользователя(например, durov): ')  # введи имя друга

api = vk.get_api()

if username.isdigit():
    try:
        api.users.get(user_id=username)
    except vk_api.ApiError:
        print('Неверное имя пользователя.')
        sys.exit(1)
else:
    try:
        username = api.utils.resolveScreenName(screen_name=username)['object_id']
    except TypeError:
        print('Неверное имя пользователя.')
        sys.exit(1)

print('Чтобы остановить, нажмите Ctrl+C')

longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)


def delete_message(api, message_id):
    return next(iter(api.messages.delete(message_ids='{}'.format(str(message_id))).values())) == 1


try:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.from_user\
            and event.user_id == int(username) and event.attachments.get('attach1_type', '') == 'sticker':
            if delete_message(api, event.message_id):
                print('Сообщение удалено!')
            else:
                print('Что-то пошло не так...')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Останавливаю...')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Просто запускаете его `python.exe script.py`(на Windows) и следуете указаниям.

Comment: Спасибо, но, правда, пароль почему-то не вводится.

Comment: Он не отображается. Я это сделал для безопасности (:

Comment: Ну да, я уже понял. Когда ввожу пароль и имя пишет Bad password, могу ли я использовать для этого поля input, как для логина?

Comment: Спокойно можно использовать input

Comment: Чёт не работает.( Даже не выходят сообщения о том, что сообщение удалено, или "Что-то пошло не так...". Пробовал ввести имя, потом id, потом вовсе стёр/закомментировал строки с упоминанием отправителя и всё-равно не помогло. Не знаю, может у меня настолько руки кривые, что-то не так делаю)

Comment: Покажите текст ошибки. id нужно писать без префикса `id`, например `1`, а не `id1`

Comment: Во время исполнения программы ошибок не возникает. Разве что после прерывания(Ctrl+C) идёт `Traceback`...там лог вызова, потом `TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'`, но, думаю, это не значимо. Далее просто логи вызовов идут и всё.

Comment: signal не сработал... Но да ладно, это ничего страшного. Сейчас подправлю